# How do you solve this kind of homogeneous linear system?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose the matrix associated with a homogeneous linear system is 
\begin{pmatrix} -31&0&0&4\\-8&0&1&-1\\0&0&0&0\\-4&0&-2&-1\end{pmatrix} How do you solve it by applying *[Cramer's theorem](http://www.edu.lahti.fi/~lyma/Monisteet/Cramer.pdf)* (and not, say, reduction)? I normally don't have issues with this kind of problems, but the column of zeros confuses me a bit. Could you show me the process step by step, please?

Comment: You can't use Cramer's rule since (1) the system is *homogeneous*, and (2) the matrix is singular and thus its determinant is zero.

Comment: @Timbuc (1) doesn't really prevent you from applying the theorem; it just happens to give you something trivial.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Well, for non-trivial solutions it actually does as you will *always* get zeros...but then the trivial solution always exists and then what the heck does one need Cramer for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cramer's theorem cannot be applied to (coefficient) matrices with determinant zero, as is the case here.  It would seem that row-reduction is the only sensible way to approach this, then.

Comment: Why can't it be applied?

Comment: @user62029 because you divide by the determinant and you cannot divide by $0$.

Comment: Could you show me how to solve this? (Please, add as much clear details as you can, because we've not covered row-reduction yet).

Answer (score 0):

The column of zeroes will give you a zero determinant... as would the row of zeroes. So Cramer's theorem doesn't apply directly - but we could ignore the zero row and zero column and work on the reduced matrix, if that makes sense for the system under consideration.